# recover boot-loader on osx

Tags: macos, boot, partitioning

On a MacBook Pro a tripple-boot (OSX, Windows, Ubuntu) was installed. For that, two partitions have been made, a 149.4 GB and a 100 GB. While not using Windows and Ubuntu, the 100 GB partition was fused with the Recovery HD, resulting in a more than 100 GB Recovery HD partition. To fuse the Recovery HD with the Macintosh HD, the Recovery HD partition was deleted. However the fuse was not successful and errored in "You can't perform this resize unless it has a booter". Now the MacBook Pro boots in Windows showing a blue screen with a message such as: "Recovery Your PC needs to be repaired ...". There is also no OSX to boot into while holding down the alt key. OSX as the operating system is still on the SSD but the boot-loader is missing.

How can booting in OSX be restored?

How can Windows and Linux be completely removed?

How can the Macintosh HD partition be expanded to the max possible volume of the 256 GB SSD?

Below outputs from `diskutil list` and `gpt -r show /dev/disk0` which I gathered from a recovery boot with command+R

> -bash-3.2# diskutil list
>
> /dev/disk0
>
> #:                 TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER
>
> 0: GUID_partition_scheme  *251.0 GB disk0
>
> 1: EFI EFI 209.7 MB disk0s1
>
> 2:Apple_CoreStorage  149.4 GB disk0s2
>
> /dev/disk1#: TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER
>
> 0: Apple_partition_scheme *1.3 GB disk1
>
> 1: Apple_partition_map 30.7 KB disk1s1
>
> 2: Apple_HFS OS X Base System 1.3 GB disk1s2
>
> /dev/disk2
>
> ...
>
> /dev/disk12

And of the gpt

> gpt -r show /dev/disk0
>
> start size index contents
>
> 0 1 PMBR
>
> 1 1 Pri GPT header
>
> 2 32 Pri GPT table
>
> 34 6
>
> 40 409600 1 GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-...
>
> 409640 291740880 2 GPT part - 53746F72-6167-...
>
> 292150520 198084199
>
> 490234719 32 Sec GPT table
>
> 490234751 1 Sec GPT header

Comment: Simplest would be boot to Internet Recovery [Cmd/opt/R at the chimes] then format the drive from scratch. Fresh install macOS then restore from Time Machine.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thank's for the tip, did exactly how you proposed, turned out just perfect.